# Firebase & Swift - delay change of ViewController until data is read

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have implemented a login to load data from a real-time database every time a user logs in. When the user has successfully logged in, the data is being read - the problem is that `AppDelegate` changes the `ViewController` faster than the data is being read. Therefore, nothing will be displayed until the app is closed again.

**Is there a way to delay the change of the view until the data is read?**

`didFinishLaunchingOptions()` inside `AppDelegate`:

```
let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if user != nil {
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootPageViewController") as! RootPageViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsTableViewController") as! SettingsTableViewController
        vc.runResetData()

        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

`LoginViewController`:

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let email = emailInput.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordInput.text else { return }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            self.readData()
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error logging in: ", error!.localizedDescription)

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Fehler beim Einloggen", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Verstanden", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
} 

func readData() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let monthlyStartKmData = value?["monthlyStartKm"] as? Int ?? 0
        let currentKmData = value?["currentKm"] as? Int ?? 0
        ...


        startKm = monthlyStartKmData
        currentKm = currentKmData
        ...


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a possibility to delay the change of view until Firebase was able to load its data:

> databaseRef.observeSingleEvent

Working code:

```
let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            if user != nil {
                databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
                    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootPageViewController") as! RootPageViewController
                    self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                })
            } else {
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsTableViewController") as! SettingsTableViewController
                vc.runResetData()

                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't as the call to listen is asynchronous so it's run with a delay while the rootVC is setted , you need to show A loader like

```
 let vc = UIViewController()
 vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
 self.window?.rootViewController = vc
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()    
 let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in 
   .....
 }
```

Inside `AppDelegate`

```
if FIRAuth.auth().currentUser != nil {
   // go to home , if you went before you should have km month values cached 
}
else {
  // go to login
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the function of "tag"?

Comment: to be able remove

Comment: Please find the new version in the edit above - is this how it should look like, because unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: see edit... assign a temporary vc and add activity loader to it as it' ll be shown until the listener triggers

Comment: So in theory it should display `vc` until the listener triggers?

Comment: If so, the listener is being triggered instantly - the problem is that the `func readData()` takes a while to read the database.

Comment: yes , you can also make this cover as uiview above login vc and if there is a user change the root if not remove the cover to show the login screen many alternatives , you nest 2 asynchronous methods the `signin` and `readData` so there is a delay

Comment: this is the only way that should happens in login after that in next launches  check the currentuser and goto home then you can observe thses values in home

Comment: Could you please illustrate this in greater detail in an edit? I'm slowly becoming desperate.

Comment: you can cache `monthlyStartKm` and `currentKm`  say inside userdefaults and check their values when open in home instead of getting them again , also note this depends in whether they are realtime or user can login from another device so take care of that

Comment: I found a solution to delay the execution of the code until Firebase had the chance to load its data - see answer below.

Comment: Thank you anyways!